# Extract data from nested arrays

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, transpose

I have the following array (via `var_dump`) `$results`:

```
array(4) { 
    [0]=> array(5) { 
        [0]=> array(1) { ["evtId"]=> string(1) "2" } 
        [1]=> array(1) { ["evtId"]=> string(1) "3" } 
        [2]=> array(1) { ["evtId"]=> string(1) "4" } 
        [3]=> array(1) { ["evtId"]=> string(1) "5" } 
        [4]=> array(1) { ["evtId"]=> string(1) "6" } 
    [1]=> array(5) { 
        [0]=> array(1) { ["evtLocation"]=> string(2) "11 St Paul" } 
        [1]=> array(1) { ["evtLocation"]=> string(5) "12412 Horace St" } 
        [2]=> array(1) { ["evtLocation"]=> string(14) "Friends Center" } 
        [3]=> array(1) { ["evtLocation"]=> string(14) "Friends Center" } 
        [4]=> array(1) { ["evtLocation"]=> string(14) "Friends Center" } 
    [2]=> array(5) { 
        [0]=> array(1) { ["evtDate"]=> string(1) "11/12/2011" } 
        [1]=> array(1) { ["evtDate"]=> string(1) "06/05/2012" } 
        [2]=> array(1) { ["evtDate"]=> string(1) "10/10/2010" } 
        [3]=> array(1) { ["evtDate"]=> string(1) "06/06/2012" } 
        [4]=> array(1) { ["evtDate"]=> string(1) "10/12/2012" } 
    [3]=> array(5) { 
        [0]=> array(1) { ["evtType"]=> string(4) "Fun" } 
        [1]=> array(1) { ["evtType"]=> string(6) "Random" } 
        [2]=> array(1) { ["evtType"]=> string(9) "Childcare" } 
        [3]=> array(1) { ["evtType"]=> string(9) "Childcare" } 
        [4]=> array(1) { ["evtType"]=> string(9) "Childcare" }
```

I'm using this array to pull database information into a function that builds a table. However, I need this to end up in the following format:

```
$rows[] = array('2', '11 St Paul', '11/12/2011', 'Fun');
```

I've really only been able to get this far:

```
foreach ($events as $field_arr) {
  //this gives me 4 arrays, each array containing all of the records for one field type.
}
```

Now I need to loop through each of the four arrays, take one value from the same index and add it to the `$rows[]` array, which I can pass to the table building function. I've tried variations of the following (inside the initial foreach loop)

```
 $x = count($result[0]); //this gives the number of fields
 for ($i = 0; $i < $x; $i++) {
    rows[$i] = $field_array[$i];
 }
```

I've been trying variations for half the day, with little luck (I'm ending up with arrays containing 4 times as many elements as I need, and having a hard time getting rid of the final array keys (`['evtType']` etc).
If anyone can help point me in the right direction I'd greatly appreciate it.

Comment: That's do-able, but annoying. Are you sure you can't change the code that generates it instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most code posted here seems quite verbose, so here's a short version:

```
$rows = array();
foreach ($results as $pairs)
{
    foreach ($pairs as $rowNumber => $pair)
    {
        // current($pair) will give you the value
        // you could use key($pair) to get the key too
        $rows[$rowNumber][] = current($pair);
    }
}
```

That's pretty much it. Each element of `$results` holds a list of key=>value pairs and we're only interested in the value of each pair. The index of the pair is the index of the row, which we store in `$rowNumber`. I've run it and it seems to produce the expected results.

Comment: Nice. Just thinking about what happens if `current($pair)` returns `FALSE` because the internal pointer points beyond the end of the elements list. The code does not reset that list prior accessing it. `reset()` might be better, because it does the same as well while taking care to move on to the first element which is needed.

Comment: `foreach` operates on a copy of the array, so the pointer points to the first element and you'd need to execute `next($pair)` inside of the inner loop to move it. Otherwise, you could use `end()` instead of `current()`, which is what I usually use and recommend. I'm using `current()` here because it mirrors `key()` from the comment. HTH.

Answer (score 3):

Probably the shortest way:

```
$combined = array_map(function ($a, $b, $c, $d) { return $a + $b + $c + $d; }, $results[0], $results[1], $results[2], $results[3]);
```

Or, automatically scalable to accommodate any number of result elements:

```
$combined = call_user_func_array('array_map', array_merge(array(function () {
                $args = func_get_args();
                return call_user_func_array('array_merge', $args);
            }), $results));
```

Both merge every *nth* element of each array node into a new array.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the array is always the right sizes (and not "jagged")

```
$field_count = count($original);
$item_count = count($original[0]);

$items = array_fill(0,$item_count,array());

for($i = 0; $i < $item_count; $i++){
    for($j = 0; $j < $field_count; $j++){
        $inner = $original[$j][$i][0]; // Grab the innermost array
        $temp = array_values($inner); // Only take the values, discard "evtId" etc.
        // (PHP doesn't support array indices right after function call)
        $items[$i][] = $temp[0]; // Append value to item
    }
}
```

BTW, you can often use `var_export(x,true)` instead of `var_dump(x)` to get re-pasteable PHP.

Comment: Perhaps you meant `array_values` values instead of `array_keys`?

Comment: Yeah, I noticed when adding comments ;)

Comment: NP, I was pretty close to such an answer as well, so that's why I ran over it ;)

Comment: IMO "Using ginormous multidimensional arrays that are sometimes numeric and sometimes associative everywhere" is a strong PHP antipattern. (Too much aversion to just making a class to represent things sanely.)

Comment: ... it does not support that yet, until now often list() can help: `list($items[$i][]) = array_values($inner);`

Comment: I find that--used carefully--`&` references can make it much easier to modify arrays.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your original array is assigned to a variable named `$data`:

```
$data = array(...);

$colCount = count($data);
$rowCount = $colCount > 0 ? count($data[0]) : 0;

$rows = array();
for ($r = 0; $r < $rowCount; $r++) {
    $record = array();
    for ($c = 0; $c < $colCount; $c++) {
        $key = key($data[$c][$r]);
        $value = $data[$c][$r][$key];
        $record[$key] = $value;
    }
    $rows[] = $record;
}
```

Comment: `$data[$c][$r][0]` & `$data[$c][$r][0][$key]`

Answer (score 1):

As much as the data is stacked into each other, you need to fetch from it. Just not only create one iteration but four, as your data structure has four levels as well:

```
foreach($original as $fieldIndex => $fields) { 
    foreach($fields as $valueIndex => $envelope) {
        foreach($envelope as $valueEntry) {
            foreach($valueEntry as $key => $value) {
                printf("%d - %d - %s: '%s'\n", $fieldIndex, $valueIndex, $key, $value);
                $build[$valueIndex][$key]=$value;
            }
        }
    }
}

var_dump($build);
```

I've put some output inside there so you can see what has been collected in the innermost part. That's the place where all data is collected and you can re-order it according to your needs.

This only works if you have always the same number of elements on each corresponding level to get a result that's well formed. However, the code-example already works when there are always the same level nesting, so not every item needs to have all keys.

Edit: corrected from three to four levels.

Answer (score 0):

This is not intended toward the poster, but to those who criticize me for saying I did not test my code.  DISCLAIMER:  I am not here to write your application for you.  I will attempt to provide you with usable code, but I in no way guarantee that this is drag and droppable, plug and play, or anything else.  If you want that type of service, then please hire myself or one of the many other competent professional developers you find on this site.

That being said...  this code should get you going in the direction you need to go,  I have tested it, but do not guarantee it will work with your particular array structure, but should be enough to give you an idea of what you need to do.

Hope this helps!

```
foreach($events as $value1) {

 foreach($value1 as $value2) {

   $new_arr[] = array(
    'evtId' => $value2['evtId'],
    'evtLocation' =>$value2['evtLocation'],
    'evtDate' => $value2['evtDate'],
    'evtType' =>$value2['evtType']) ;
   }

}
```

Comment: @Josh Davis: I don't see that anywhere in the FAQ. If you do not agree with that answer, just don't upvote it.

Comment: Just tested it, works fine.  Here is proof. http://brianjeffreypatterson.com/testme.php

Comment: @Josh Davis  -- Yeah I don't see it in the FAQ either, and thanks for downvoting me for posting VALID WORKING code.  Just because I gave the disclaimer its not tested.  Not nice.

Comment: @netcoder: I don't see anything in the FAQ about posting about my cats, yet you would find it strange if I did. - @Brian: I didn't vote on your answer either way but I understand that people would downvote an answer that starts with "I didn't test it but". That's what I was about to do when I decided to spend 30s of my time improving the site by asking you to take a minute to test your code instead of rushing for a mediocre untested answer.

Comment: Well, if I don't then there will be 5 mediocre answers ahead of me by the time I post my well thought out and tested answer and mine wont even see the light of day down at the bottom of the list and never get upvoted.. so what can i do ..   se la vi

Comment: @Josh Davis: I'm sorry, but from what I've seen on this question, you haven't been helpful at all. You've put the exact same comment twice on two different answers, didn't flag, didn't vote, and didn't answer. At least, he's trying to help. It's just that it is unconstructive really, so no hard feelings. :)

Comment: @Josh Davis - and you know what, I've seen people post psuedo code on here,  so as long as the person gets the idea of what to do.  I'm not getting paid for this, so I'm not sitting here delivering fully tested code.  I'm just trying to help the guy get an idea of what he needs to do because he is stuck.  And like netcoder said, instead of criticizing everyone, why don't you try to help instead.

Comment: Posting random, *non-working* code does not help at all, that's what I'm trying to explain here. If you don't have time to test the code, don't post it, it's much better than the alternative. So I repeat, if you want to help **please refrain from posting untested code**. That will save everybody's time.

Comment: @Brian: you said *"if I don't then there will be 5 mediocre answers ahead of me"*. Here, you've posted non-working code so you **were** among the 5 mediocre answers ahead of the right one. What good does it do to anybody? StackOverflow is a big race to post bad code that somehow gets upvoted despite not working, and you're only furthering it.

Comment: I haven't had the time to review any of the code yet, but I do appreciate the help and appreciate the fact that @Brian Paterson informed me that the code wasn't tested. That puts the onus on me to test the code and I'm the one who's stuck, so ultimately it's my responsibility anyhow. Maybe this conversation should unfold further in Meta?